# Using dist function in gulp

Tags: gulp, polymer

I am working on a Polymer app. I'm trying to add ES6 support. As part of that, I'm following the directions provided [here](https://github.com/PolymerElements/polymer-starter-kit/blob/master/docs/add-es2015-support-babel.md). The addition makes a call to some function called `dist`.

Where does `dist` come from? When I run gulp from the command line, I get an error that says:

```
ReferenceError: dist is not defined
    at Gulp.<anonymous> (/Users/user/MyApp/gulpfile.js:122:21)
```

What is `dist`? I can't find a description of it anywhere. Just to avoid confusion, the offending line looks like this:

```
.pipe(gulp.dest(dist()));
```

I know what `dest` is. However, it's the `dist` that is causing problems.

Answer (score -1):

'dist' in gulp is short for destination. It is the location to where a particular task will output when it's finished. That output could be a compressed image or minified code. If there is no destination for it to go specified or it is an incorrect path or worse it has not been stated where it should go when complete then an error can occur.

Comment: Hello, I thought `dest` was short for destination. I'm asking about `dist`. One of the offending lines in the gulpfile.js is `.pipe(gulp.dest(dist()));`. As you can see, both `dest` and `dist` are used. I'm having problems with the `dist` part.

Comment: Hi, I have done a little looking around on 'dist' and no one seems to really be having this exact issue so I can only assume to put quotes around the dist and remove the extra (), it will then output whatever the function is doing to a dist folder in the root of the project. It could be a variable on the other hand as Gulp is built on JS.